# What are food combinations that trick your taste buds into tasting sweet?

Tags: flavor

I recently tried unflavored yoghurt with a teaspoon of cinnamon, and for some reason, the combination tasted sweet. Are there any food combinations that accomplish this?

The yoghurt was non-fat; I'm assuming that because both ingredients contained carbs consequently any other combinations that also work would perhaps need to be 'carby' ingredients.

The nutrition facts of the yoghurt per 100 ml:

energy: 21 kcal

protein: 1.8 g

carbohydrates: 2.8 g

fat: 0.3 g

sodium: 0.25 g

Comment: Just because it's unflavored doesn't mean it's not full of sugar or a sugar substitute.  Part of the major problem with "non-fat" yogurt is that it's so high in calories because of sugar content. Without knowing what's actually in your particular yogurt, we can't really answer the question, though.

Comment: When I say "what's in" I mean the ingredients list :D

Comment: related to http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36560/is-cinnamon-sweet , I think

Answer (score 4):

Though your yogurt was unflavored, it almost certainly still contained lactose (milk sugar), so it should still taste a bit sweet regardless of whatever was added to it. And as Catija points out, "unflavored" doesn't apply to added sugar, of which there can be quite a lot in yogurt (and almost every other prepared food).

Comment: yep... compare some brands of soy milk yoghurt, they taste far more sour than dairy yoghurt (which can be advantageous)...

Comment: I very much doubt that this was the answer in this case. First, acid and sweeteners "counter" each other, so with enough acid you can't taste a sugar (and the other way round). Standard yogurt, with 4-5 g of lactose, does not taste sweet at all, probably because it has enough lactic acid - and the yogurt the OP had only has 2.8 g or less of lactose, and certainly no added sugar (it would have showed up on the nutrition label as more carbs).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why, but Salt and flour taste sweet.
Mix a small amount of each and give it a taste.

Comment: Alton Brown did a great "Good Eats" about that (sort of). [The Ballad of Salty and Sweet](http://www.goodeatsfanpage.com/Season13/salty_desserts/salty_sweet_trans.htm).

Comment: I'll have to give that a watch. It's something I found out when baking.